# How to use AppStore connect API with my mac, announced in WWDC18?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, wwdc, xcode10, ios12

I have seen the demo in WWDC18 related video here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/303/

but it is not from the scratch. I don't see that which tool they have used and where we need to start it. Can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 5):

I watched that video too today and I wanted to use these API features, as for now 19-6-2018 this is still marked as coming soon... based on the App Store Connect website https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/

In addition, the new API Keys tab under the main App Store Connect is not available yet.This is the starting point to issue / create the API keys.

I am on look out and waiting...

[image: Apple still shows it as coming soon as of 19-6-2018]

Comment: seems that they want to mimic the Android Play Store config style, but not sure if was ever ready in WWDC 2018 from the start. thanks for updates guys

Comment: TestFlight invite via link mentioned in Coming Soon is already out, hopefully they'll release the REST API soon as well.

Comment: It's end of October and this is still Coming Soon. Come one Apple!

Answer (score 2):

The App Store Connect API is now available. You can find out more here:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/

The general steps are:

1. [Request access to the API](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api).

   Your Team Agent (with the Legal role) will need to do this part.
2. [Create and download an API key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api).

   Anyone with Admin access can do this. Each key you create can only be downloaded once, and should be kept safe.
3. [Use the information on the Keys tab + your private key to generate a token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests).

   You can find libraries for many languages to make this easy [here](http://jwt.io).
4. Supply the JWT as a bearer token in the HTTP `Authorization` header when making requests.

For example:

```
GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps
Authorization: Bearer XYZ123
```

Where `XYZ123` is your JWT. (Your real JWT will be much longer.)

Available API endpoints are documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi

Comment: How long does it take to get the requested API key? I have requested the key a couple of dyas ago, but still nothing.

Comment: @SaschaSimon same here... requested access on Nov 4, 2018 and still no access

Comment: Organizations get access immediately, it’s delayed only for Individual developers.

Comment: It's the end of January and I still did not get a API key yet.

Comment: @inexcitus does that mean people can't use the appstoreconnect api anymore?

Comment: I have since received my API key, so I assume that you still can use the API once you get a key.

Answer (score 0):

[App Store Connect API available here now](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi).